# How to install GPS common?

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm currently trying to set up a GPS receiver and base station my boss purchased to work in ROS. It is a trimble Ag GPS 542 GNSS receiver ( http://ssmgps.com/pdf/AGPB_AgGPS542_BaseAndReceiver_ROW_16502.pdf). I am trying to get it to work with the gps_common package, found here: http://answers.ros.org/question/75337/gps_common-installation/

However, when I install the package, using either

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-gps-umd
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/ktossell/gps_umd
```

I get a gps_common directory containing a cmake directory, a msg directory, and a package.xml, but no src directory or CMakeLists.  Thus when I try to run nodes that are supposed to be within this package (for example,

```
rosrun gps_common utm_odometry_node
```

), it just freezes and doesn't work.  I've encountered similar problems before when downloading random ros packages, and guess the solution must somehow have to do with somehow cmaking the cmake folders or files, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.  If I cmake an individual file I get the error

```
 CMake Error: The source directory "/opt/ros/hydro/share/gps_common/cmake/<whatever_file_I_choose>.cmake" is a file, not a directory.
```

, and if I try to cmake the cmake directory, I get

```
  CMake Error: The source directory "/opt/ros/hydro/share/gps_common/cmake" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

Amyone know what I'm doing wrong here?  Am I at least on the right track, or is there some other way to access these nodes short of manually creating my own package and copying the contents of each file into it from github, then catkin_making? (which I have tried successfully in the past, but am tired of doing)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190098/how-to-install-gps-common?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `git clone https://github.com/ktossell/gps_umd.git` instead of just /gps_umd.

Or just do a cheap and dirty way with downloading the zip file, and extracting it to your workspace.

Either way, make sure you go into the root of gps_common package and run `rosmake`.

../catkin_ws/src/gps_common       ---->>      `rosmake`

Then build everything with `catkin_make`

../catkin_ws/       ---->>      catkin_make

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-08-13**:
Ok, I removed the package and redownloaded it with the modified git clone line you suggested.  Then I navigate into gps_common, and rosmake, but receive the following response: [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] No package or stack specified.  And current directory 'gps_common' is not a package name or stack name.
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: []
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/randy/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140813-145138
[ rosmake ] Expanded args [] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-08-13**:
I also tried rosmake gps (tab complete), and it filled in gpsd_client, which I then ran.  No errors, but I'm not sure if this is what I wanted to do.  Then I catkin_made just in case I did anything good.  Again, I can find no reference in the build log to anything clontaining "gps."

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-08-13**:
Although the error I receive when I try to run the node as originally described is slightly different (more complete now)!:
[rospack] Error: stack/package gps_common not found
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named utm_odometry_node below

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-14**:
manually download the zip, extract just the gps_common folder inside to zip into your own src folder, go to the gps_common folder in your src folder, type rosmake

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting this error message when trying to build the gps_common:

```
Building CXX object gps_umd/gps_common/CMakeFiles/gps_common/utm_odometry_node.dir/src/utm_odometry_node.cpp.o
The bug is not reproducible, so it is likely a hardware or OS problem.
make[2]: *** [gps_umd/gpsd_client/CMakeFiles/gpsd_client.dir/src/client.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [gps_umd/gpsd_client/CMakeFiles/gpsd_client.dir/all] Error 2
```

Ran this:
sudo apt-get install gpsd

and it built okay.

---

Originally posted by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) with karma: 90 on 2015-08-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the maintainer of `gps_umd` has changed, make sure to clone the correct/most recent repo. I had to install `libgps-dev`, before I could build the gps_umd package. So here are the steps, which I made:

```
sudo apt-get install libgps-dev
cd catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/swri-robotics/gps_umd.git
cd ..
catkin_make
```

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2